# how the session will map back to server if it reboots

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have dough't  i have a server page written in asp.net and i have used session in pages. For example (an user login and start working in page for 10-15 min) while working there was some issue and my server is down and starts again. Now think i have given session timeout=20, how will my session id will know this is my server or how it works i have asked many people i am not satisfied with their answers. Please can any body help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: better add your code, which would be more clear and understandable

Comment: no this was my interview question.

Comment: I think this question is too broad for Stack Overflow without showing any code.

Comment: @hyugaazia StackOverflow is not the place to get your excersice solved.

Comment: then why do you have stack over when my technical question is not answered..every were we cannot use codes to explain... as a developer you should know that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using InProc session state (the default in ASP.NET) you will lose all session data on a reboot. To prevent this from happening you will have to configure out-of-process session state in the Web.Config and have a State Server or SQL Server that keeps the session state data.

Note that if you choose to do this, everything you put into session state must be serializable as it is serialized before sending to the state server.

**Edit**

To set up a state server, Microsoft has some pretty decent docs on the Technet site here: [State server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732412(v=ws.10).aspx) or [Sql Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753897(v=ws.10).aspx). Additionally, searching for `out of process session aspnet` will give you some excellent blogs on the subject.

Do note that if you want to protect against reboots of the webserver, the State Server service should not run on the same machine as the webserver. When using Sql server this is obviously less of an issue.

Comment: Thanks Robba, can you suggest me some pages on session, so that i can have a clear idea on sessions..anyway thanks for answering i got the scratch..